# Xamarin.android- how to make encryption/decryption of images faster

Tags: c#, android, encryption, xamarin.android

I want users to select images/videos from gallery and secure their images within my app. for that, I encrypt those images. Encryption over images works correctly(I think so !). It takes 1.5 to 2 seconds for 8MB image. but what about videos ? videos might be in GBs. So it would take a lot time. And even in encryption/decryption I have to perform action on every single image, that can cause memory issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015194/android-aes-128-encryption-decryption-of-file-is-very-slow-how-can-i-increase-t) link helped me to achieve this.

If you see, ES file explorer also provides encryption and decryption on images/videos. and it completes operation of GBs within just few seconds. So can I know which technique/algorithm these guys use ?

or even if I use my own way, is there any trick to make it faster ? or is there any other way to make file inaccessible to user ? Changing MIME type will work ?

Even if I change extension or make it hidden by adding . before the file name, user can still view images in some file explorer.

Actually for `xamarin`, I didn't find any post/blog related to encrypting decrypting file. All they provide is solution on string.

i would really appreciate if someone guides me for this issue.

**EDIT**

Hello, @Joe Lv, As I said I tried your method in which encryption was slow but decryption was very fast. So I implemented the same decryption technique you used to encrypt things. And It works !! but I want to know if this is valid or not.

Now my encrypt method looks like this :

```
public void encrypt(string filename)
    {

        // Here you read the cleartext.
        try
        {
            File extStore = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryMovies);
            startTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            Android.Util.Log.Error("Encryption Started", extStore + "/" + filename);

            // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by
            // another stream.
        //    createFile(filename, extStore);
        //    System.IO.FileStream fs=System.IO.File.OpenRead(extStore + "/" + filename);
      //      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(extStore + "/" + filename + ".aes", false);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath, false);
            System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filepath + filename);
            // Create cipher

            // Length is 16 byte
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] raw = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sKey);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ivParameter));//
            cipher.Init(CipherMode.EncryptMode, skeySpec, iv);

            // Wrap the output stream
           // CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fs, cipher);
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fs, cipher);

            // Write bytes
            int b;
            byte[] d = new byte[512 * 1024];
            while ((b = fis.Read(d)) != -1)
            {
                cos.Write(d, 0, b);
            }
            // Flush and close streams.
            fos.Flush();
            fos.Close();
            cos.Close();
   fis.Close();

            stopTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            Android.Util.Log.Error("Encryption Ended", extStore + "/5mbtest/" + filename + ".aes");
            Android.Util.Log.Error("Time Elapsed", ((stopTime - startTime) / 1000.0) + "");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Error("lv",e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: For images, why not use [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to encrypt them?

Comment: You can use `CipherOutputStream` to decrypt  file.

Comment: I think ES file explorer may be just open a thread to encrypt/decrypt and just show result in UI thread, so it is slow in work thread actually, this just a guess.

Comment: Here is the one approach explained using android keystore : https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2021/07/android-keystore-based-encryption-and.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't find any post/blog related to encrypting decrypting file

You can use `CipherOutputStream` and `CipherInputStream` to achieve it.

Here is my test demo, you can try it, and you need push a video file named *`videoplayback.mp4`* into your phone which path is `/storage/sdcard/Movies`, so you can test my code directly.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Javax.Crypto.Spec;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.IO;
using Javax.Crypto;
using System.Text;

namespace EncryTest
{
    [Activity(Label = "EncryTest", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        long stopTime, startTime;
        private string sKey = "0123456789abcdef";//key，
        private string ivParameter = "1020304050607080";
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            encrypt("videoplayback.mp4");
            decrypt("videoplayback.mp4");
        }

        public void encrypt(string filename)
        {

            // Here you read the cleartext.
            try
            {
                File extStore = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryMovies);
                startTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Encryption Started", extStore + "/" + filename);

                // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by
                // another stream.
                createFile(filename, extStore);
                System.IO.FileStream fs=System.IO.File.OpenRead(extStore + "/" + filename);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(extStore + "/" + filename + ".aes", false);

                // Length is 16 byte
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                byte[] raw = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sKey);
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ivParameter));//
                cipher.Init(CipherMode.EncryptMode, skeySpec, iv);

                // Wrap the output stream
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fs, cipher);
                // Write bytes
                int b;
                byte[] d = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                while ((b = cis.Read(d)) != -1)
                {
                    fos.Write(d, 0, b);
                }
                // Flush and close streams.
                fos.Flush();
                fos.Close();
                cis.Close();
                stopTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Encryption Ended", extStore + "/5mbtest/" + filename + ".aes");
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Time Elapsed", ((stopTime - startTime) / 1000.0) + "");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Error("lv",e.Message);
            }

        }


        private void createFile(string filename, File extStore)
        {
            File file = new File(extStore + "/" + filename + ".aes");

            if (filename.IndexOf(".") != -1)
            {
                try
                {
                    file.CreateNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Android.Util.Log.Error("lv",e.Message);
                }
                Android.Util.Log.Error("lv","file created");
            }
            else
            {
                file.Mkdir();
                Android.Util.Log.Error("lv","folder created");
            }

            file.Mkdirs();
        }
        public void decrypt(string filename)
        {
            try
            {

                File extStore = Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryMovies);
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Decryption Started", extStore + "");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(extStore + "/" + filename + ".aes");

                createFile(filename, extStore);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(extStore + "/" + "decrypted" + filename, false);
                System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(extStore + "/" + "decrypted" + filename);
                // Create cipher

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                byte[] raw = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sKey);
                SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ivParameter));//
                cipher.Init(CipherMode.DecryptMode, skeySpec, iv);

                startTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fs, cipher);
                int b;
                byte[] d = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                while ((b = fis.Read(d)) != -1)
                {
                    cos.Write(d, 0, b);
                }

                stopTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond;

                Android.Util.Log.Error("Decryption Ended", extStore + "/" + "decrypted" + filename);
                Android.Util.Log.Error("Time Elapsed", ((stopTime - startTime) / 1000.0) + "");

                cos.Flush();
                cos.Close();
                fis.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Error("lv", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The video just for test, you can get the video file from another path, just a little change will be good.

About the path `/storage/sdcard/Movies`, I think a picture will be better to understand it [image]

Comment: Thanks @Joe Lv for comment. Actually I tried this method earlier with some changes. But one question, if user selects multiple photos at a time,lets say 5, then 1 iv is enough for these 5 encryption ? or I have to generate 5 iv for that ? With this method, i was able to encrypt but getting error in decryption. It says you must supply iv for decryption and how can I remember iv ? in global variable or in shared preferences ? I was confused about iv so i am trying to switch the method. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, generate 5 iv. Add the iv to the file name. By `getting error in decryption`, what error did you get?

Comment: Hi @Joe Lv. As I mentioned error says,' you must supply iv to decrypt data' actually I am not at working place so can't tell exact error. Tried your method but It encrypts file at the same location of file. Actually I want encrypted file at different location. For that in encryption I used `FileInputStream` and `CipherOutPutStream`. And reverse in decryption but using that not able to get expected result. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hello, little bit more research on `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` was enough to understand your code. It works as expected. But one more question, your decryption method(using CypherOutputStream) is much faster than encryption. So i used same technique in encryption also. And it also speed up. Can you pls explain what is difference between these two methods ?

Comment: By `I want encrypted file at different location`, you just need to change the path of file, or you can tell me where is your files.

Comment: By `in encryption I used FileInputStream and CipherOutPutStream`, it is incorrect. You need use the `CipherInputStream` which wrapped `FileInputStream` and the `FileOutputStream` to encrypt. It means that `CipherInputStream` will encrypt the data when you are reading and `FileOutputStream` will write the encryption data to the new file. [Here is the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html)