# Xamarin.Android - Video decryption takes too much time

Tags: android, xamarin, encryption, xamarin.android, aes

I want to encrypt/decrypt videos using AES algorithm in android. For that I refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306345/xamarin-android-how-to-make-encryption-decryption-of-images-faster) link. By using method mentioned in the link, I was able to complete my task. Videos small in size are performed faster. but for large files it takes very long time. like for around 600MB video, this method took around 45 Sec - 1 min duration.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Thank you.

EDIT :
Sorry for being little bit unclear. Forgot to tell you what I thought about the solution could be.
If there is file of 2GB can not we divide it into 4 sets of 500 mb and then perform operation while playing ut ? As 500 mb doesnt take much time. Is this possible ? I searched but could not found satisfactory answer.

Comment: 45 seconds sounds about right for the size you say the video is.

Comment: Sounds like you're decrypting the file and then playing it.  Why are you not streaming it?

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron for comment. You are saying right. But what if I have 2GB or more size video ? User will be irritated if loading indicator is displayed for long time. For encryption user can wait, as his file is being secured. But at the time of playing video, we can't play with his patience 

Comment: Thanks @Luke for the comment but I want to do this task without internet.

Comment: My suggestion has nothing to do with using an internet connection.  You should be streaming the ciphertext through your decryption algorithm and directly to the video player.  There will be no delay at all.

Comment: Can you pls give me example ? I was searching for streaming video file and they all say a about internet stuff.

Comment: Read about `CipherStream`.

Comment: Hello, could you pls give me any link to refer or example. Because I am using CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream in decryption process. But don't know how to stream it to the videoview. Thanks.