# xamarin.android video streaming in videoview

Tags: android, xamarin, encryption, xamarin.android

I am encrypting my videos using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306345/xamarin-android-how-to-make-encryption-decryption-of-images-faster) link and store it in my application folder. But for large videos say, 2GB, it takes much time to decrypt and then play. so user has to wait for 1.5-2 minutes to decrypt selected video and then play it.

For that, I searched for offline video streaming. And I found [this](https://www.cumulations.com/blogs/29/OfflineVideoStreaming). I have same scenario but instead of downloading, I am encrypting videos from gallery. and I have used different encryption alogithm.

When I tried above link, my connection is lost everytime it goes in while loop. In catch, I get `Connection is reset` error. Also I didn't  get some variables there. like, `total`, `readbyte` and `pos` variables. can anybody please explain?

I really want to decrypt and play videos at the same time. so user experience will be good.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
Here is my sample code :

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Java.IO;
using Javax.Crypto;
using Javax.Crypto.Spec;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Java.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SecretCalc
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", 
MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    VideoView video;
    Button encrypt, decrypt;
    private string sKey = "0123456789abcdef";//key，
    private string ivParameter = "1020304050607080";
    string path = "/sdcard/Download/";
    string destpath = "/sdcard/test/";
    string filename = "video1.mp4";
    Stream outputStream;
    string date = "20180922153533.mp4"; // Already Encrypted File Name

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        video = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView);
        encrypt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEncrypt);
        decrypt = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDecrypt);

        encrypt.Click += Encrypt_Click;
        decrypt.Click += Decrypt_ClickAsync;
    }


    private async void Decrypt_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        video.SetVideoPath("http://0.0.0.0:9990/");
        video.Prepared += Video_Prepared;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
                serverSocket.Bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 9990));

                // this is a blocking call, control will be blocked until client sends the request
                Socket finalAccept = serverSocket.Accept();
                outputStream = finalAccept.OutputStream;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        });

        await Task.Run(() => DecryptThroughSocket());

    }

    private void Video_Prepared(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        video.Start();
    }

    private bool DecryptThroughSocket()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] raw = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sKey);
            byte[] iv = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ivParameter);

            int count = 0, pos = 0, total = 0, readbyte;

            byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            readbyte = data.Length;
            long lenghtOfFile = new Java.IO.File(Path.Combine(path, date)).Length();

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(Path.Combine(destpath, date));

            while ((count = inputStream.Read(data, 0, readbyte)) != -1)
            {
                if (count < readbyte)
                {
                    if ((lenghtOfFile - total) > readbyte)
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int seccount = inputStream.Read(data, pos, (readbyte - pos));
                            pos = pos + seccount;
                            if (pos == readbyte)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // encrypt data read before writing to output stream
                byte[] decryptedData = decryptFun(raw, iv, data);
                outputStream.Write(decryptedData,0,decryptedData.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void Encrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename));

            date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".mp4";

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(destpath);

            if (!dir.Exists)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destpath);
            }

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(destpath, date));

            byte[] raw = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sKey);
            byte[] iv = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ivParameter);

            int count = 0, pos = 0, total = 0, readbyte;

            byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            readbyte = data.Length;
            long lenghtOfFile = new Java.IO.File(Path.Combine(path, filename)).Length();

            while ((count = inputStream.Read(data, 0, readbyte)) != -1)
            {
                if (count < readbyte)
                {
                    if ((lenghtOfFile - total) > readbyte)
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            int seccount = inputStream.Read(data, pos, (readbyte - pos));
                            pos = pos + seccount;
                            if (pos == readbyte)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                total += count;

                // encrypt data read before writing to output stream
                byte[] encryptedData = encryptFun(raw, iv, data);
                outputStream.Write(encryptedData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public static byte[] encryptFun(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] clear)
    {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        cipher.Init(CipherMode.EncryptMode, skeySpec, ivspec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.DoFinal(clear);
        return encrypted;
    }

    public static byte[] decryptFun(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] encrypted)
    {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.GetInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.Init(CipherMode.DecryptMode, skeySpec, ivspec);

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.DoFinal(encrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Really need to see the code that you are having a problem with (not via off-site links), review : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @SushiHangover added my code. please check.